# Unreserved account concurrency unusual default value

Tags: aws-lambda

When I create a lambda, I see `Use unreserved account concurrency` is 50. What could be the reason behind this restriction? There is no other lambdas, resources, etc, I've just started learning AWS. My colleague shows his AWS accound has 1000 by default.
Where to fix this limit?

Comment: I believe that 50 is the new default in an attempt from AWS to prevent fraud. You can contact support to have it increased up to 1,000 because that is still it the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) as a default limit of 1,000. My old accounts were 1,000 but a new account was 50 and support fixed it.